# Redirect ASP.NET Core Logs to a specific NLog file asynchronous

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, nlog

I use `NLog` for Logging in my ASP.NET Core Project in separate files:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<targets async="true">
    <target name="JsonFile" xsi:type="File" layout="${message}" fileName="${shortdate}Json.log"/>
    <target name="ServerFile" xsi:type="File" layout="${message}" fileName="${shortdate}Server.log"/>
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="JsonLog" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="JsonFile" />
    <logger name="ServerLog" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ServerFile" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

-

```
public static class Log
{
    public static Logger Json = LogManager.GetLogger("JsonLog");
    public static Logger Server = LogManager.GetLogger("ServerLog");
}
```

**My questions:**

**1.** Can I log the message of ASP.NET Core directly into the specific `ServerLog` file of `NLog`?

**2.** Can I avoid that ASP.NET Core wants to log to the Console synchronous and just use the asynchronous `ServerLog` file of `NLog` for better performance? Extensive Console Logging had dramatic impact in the performance of the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can add NLog as Microsoft Extension Logging provider with `UseNLog()` (And remove the default ASP.NET Console-provider by calling `ClearProviders()`):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Then you can can a wildcard-rule (name="*") to your NLog-config for catch-all logging:

```
<nlog>
<extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>

<targets async="true">
    <target name="JsonFile" xsi:type="File" layout="${message}" fileName="${shortdate}Json.log"/>
    <target name="ServerFile" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}${exception:format=tostring}" fileName="${shortdate}Server.log"/>
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="JsonLog" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="JsonFile" final="true" />
    <logger name="ServerLog" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ServerFile" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="ServerFile" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can I log the message of ASP.NET Core directly into the specific ServerLog file of NLog?

You have the following options:

1. Inject `ILogger<ServerLog>`, which could be a bit hacky, or
2. Inject `ILoggerProvider` (namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) and use `provider.CreateLogger("ServerLog")`, or
3. Use the `LogManager.GetLogger("ServerLog")`, although this is the non-DI approach. It could be suitable for your project.

> 2. Can I avoid that ASP.NET Core wants to log to the Console synchronous and just use the asynchronous ServerLog file of NLog for better performance? Extensive Console Logging had dramatic impact in the performance of the API.

You need indeed the `.ClearProviders()`, see this code example:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();  // <---------- clear console etc
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog();  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
```